# MVC4 routing 2 areas containing controllers with the same name

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have 2 areas in an mvc4 application and I have registered the namespace for each of the areas.

```
 public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Intergration_default",
            "Intergration/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
              constraints: null,
            namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication.Areas.Intergration.Controllers" }

        );

    } 
    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "Vend_default",
            "Vend/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional},
              constraints: null,
            namespaces: new[] { "WebApplication.Areas.MyController.Controllers" }

        );
```

I can access Intergration/MyController however when I try accessing MyController I get an error

> Multiple types were found that match the controller named 'mycontroller'. This can happen if the route that services this request ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') does not specify namespaces to search for a controller that matches the request. If this is the case, register this route by calling an overload of the 'MapRoute' method that takes a 'namespaces' parameter.

What am I doing wrong? do I need to do something extra in the global.asax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code / description you provided, it sounds like it could be a couple of things:

1. You have a controller name collision in the root controllers namespace (i.e., in the Controllers folder in the root of the project, not in an area) with another area with no constraint.
2. More likely, your second area registration for `Vend` has what looks like an incorrect namespace.  Instead of `WebApplication.Areas.MyController.Controllers` it should be `WebApplication.Areas.Vend.Controllers`.  I bet that there's a controller in your root controllers namespace that shares a controller name with something in the `Vend` area.